# Improving query speed: simple SELECT from SELECT in huge table

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I have a table contains 3 columns : age , name , nickname
I would like to get only the names (+age) where the name+age does not exist at all in nickname+age.

For example : if table : DETAILS contains 2 rows :

1. age: 5 , name: suzi, nickname: suzi
2. age:2 , name : gil, nickname: g

query will return : age:2 , name : gil

```
SELECT d1.AGE, d1.NAME
FROM DETAILS d1
WHERE d1.NAME NOT IN (SELECT d2.NICKNAME FROM DETAILS d2 WHERE d2.AGE = d1.AGE)
```

This query runs only on small data.
Any idea how to improve it?

Comment: LEFT JOIN instead of NOT IN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical point in SQL query performance is using index. So you have to have the index in the querying/joining columns and you need to use it (via join).

E.g. query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT D1.AGE, D1.NAME
FROM DETAILS D1 LEFT JOIN DETAILS D2 ON D1.AGE = D2.AGE
WHERE D1.NAME <> D2.NICKNAME
```

Note that you have to create indexes on columns AGE, NAME, AND NICKNAME beforehand to fully benefit from this query.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the result by this:

```
SELECT d1.AGE, 
       CASE WHEN d1.NAME IS NULL
            THEN d1.NIKCNAME ELSE d1.NAME END as [NewName]
FROM DETAILS d1
INNER JOIN DETAILS d2
    ON d1.AGE = d2.AGE 
WHERE d2.NAME <> d1.NICKNAME
```

Comment: This query will return all rows where the name is not equal to the nickname *in the same row*, which is not what the OP wants. They want all rows whose name/age doesn't appear as nickname/age *in any* row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use Left Join/Left Outer Join instead of WHERE ... NOT IN ...

The orders of execution of SQL

1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP